# Best practice for rendering page fragments

Tags: symfony

I have trivial complex page.
For example: content(left) and sidebar(right).
Sidebar consists of a plurality of parts. We take a look at one of theese. This fragment contains list of users(for example) subscribed to the event. The list displays only 5 users and "More" button, which loads more users when clicked (ajax).
If i use:

```
{% render controller('SomeBundle:Event:subcribers', {page: 1, limit: 5}) %}
```

Or:

```
{% render path('event_subcribers_route', {...}) %}
```

It will cause a subrequest. Notice: in this case i use this route 'event_subcribers_route' for ajax request.

Question: Maybe exists way to avoid dozens subrequests?

I'm aware that i can use services, with render logic inside them, but maybe exists some best practice for this common task.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with subrequests?

Maybe you think about more traffic between browser and server as it will happen if you have many images, css files or javascript directives in your HTML.

This is not the point using internal subrequests within the Symfony framework. actually this is just some program-logic or design pattern.

```
browser->request->[router->controller->view]->response->browser
                           ^             |
                           |             |
                           |<-subrequest-V
```

This is a very simplified schema of a subrequest like it happens using the `{% render controller() %}` in Twig. Between the `[` and `]` is inside Symfony. You just stay into the application.

Comment: What is wrong: inconvenient to debug; problems arise when there are relationships MasterRequest -> SubRequest. And subjectively(no holywars): It seems that SF inclines us to a bad practice of making these renderings. So I wondered how others are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you include that piece of HTML you will need to do the according subrequest to the database no matter which method you use.

But, you can optimize the query to recover those users. You can select only the fields you actually need (username, slug, etc.) and also you can do it on a single query. That single query will become a prepared statement and you can even put index on the table to make the query faster.

In addition, you can implement the symfony cache system to avoid those subrequest that symfony does on every load. If your snippet loads always the same 5 users or they change after X minutes you can easily implement an efficient cache.

Comment: I do not mean db queries talking about "subrequests". I don't ask about caching or optimisation ways. I am interested in architectural design for application.

Comment: My bad. I thought you were worried about extra queries to the database. What do you mean when you refer to subrequest then?

Comment: If you call $this->getRequest() in the base action(controller/action configured by current route), and then do the same in the action called by {% render controller(...) %} and you will understand what i mean. SF in that case create separate request, which doesn't have access to global query string(for example). It is called SubRequest. But for base [controller/action] it's called Master Request. All this applies only for sf2.